# request.getParameter() strips the xml value of angle brackets but request.getParameterMap() returns xml intact, can somebody explain why

Tags: xml, forms, post, getparameter

`request.getParameter()` returns XML without angle brackets

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?
```

where as `request.getParameterMap()` returns proper xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

any idea why this behavior?

Comment: and the problem is observed only with tomcat SSL enabled, tomcat with http works fine